# SQLite query returns only one row JDBC JAVA database

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, user-interface, jdbc

- I have read the previous questions but none of them seem to match my problem although they might seem similar at first. :/_

So, I am working on a local database on Java(JDBC). When I press a button I should be getting the result of a "SELECT" query. So far so good, but for some reason which my beginner brain does not understand I keep getting **only one** row from the query. I have even run the same exact query on "DB Browser for SQLite" and it returns the correct result (1+ rows) .
So this is the method I am using to get the result of the query:

```
public ResultSet returnBill(int no) throws SQLException{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM billList WHERE no = " + no + " ;";
    ResultSet thisSet =  stmt.executeQuery(sql); // stmt is a 'Statement' type variable 
    return thisSet;
}
```

The method does not crash but it only returns the very first row of a query which should return more than 2 ( **while (thisSet.next())**  RUNS ONCE). I run other "SELECT" queries on the program which are supposed to return more than one rows and they all work fine so it's not a matter of not being able to start/close the connection etc.

Below is the method being used:

```
int number  =  table.getModel().getValueAt(rows, 0);                            
ResultSet thisSet =  db.returnBill(number);
while (thisSet.next()){
        String name = thisSet.getString("name");
        int quantity = thisSet.getInt("quantity");
        // do something with the returned data 
}
```

So I get this magical number from a table (of course I made sure it's not 0, -1 etc.) and I run a query using that number. You could think of the structure of the table consisting of columns :

number |  name  | quantity  |

where 'number' is nonzero.
I understand that probably using this method to run a query on a DB might not be safe or might post security threats but it's not the case right now. I have been working on this project for quite a long time already and I have been through many silly mistakes and I think this is yet one of them. Any help is APPRECIATED ! :D

Comment: Are you debug your code? what value you give from table (value for number)? Is there exist more than one row in database with given value?

Comment: @hadi.mansouri the table gives a proper number, I tried that one out. I also print the "sql" string, the query is correct.  Yes there does exits more than one row in the database because I viewed the database on some external software "DB Browser for SQLite" where I even run the same query

Comment: Are you that the code is nor throwing some exception? Try stepping through it with a debugger

Comment: Change the query to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM billList WHERE no = " + no + " ;" and confirm number of results.

Comment: @nayakam thanks i tried it, so yes it does give me more than 1 as a count which is what I want but I don't know why the loop while (thisSet.next()) runs only once when I run the normal "Select" query :/  any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, it was a silly mistake as I expected.
So I had previously initiated a variable

```
Database db = new Database();
```

which opened the database for 2 queries (the SELECT query and an UPDATE query on another table as shown)  which would then be closed at the end of the following code.

When I removed this UPDATE query however the loop executed the correct amount of times. So it seems like the SQLite JDBC is somehow prone to running a SELECT and UPDATE query on the same **Statement** (as far as my super mega* brain perceives it.)

So I created 2 connections at the very beginning and closed them at the end using one of them for the **SELECT** and the other one for the **UPDATE** query:

```
Database db = new Database(); // open database
Database db2 = new Database(); // open another creepy one :/ 

int number  =  table.getModel().getValueAt(rows, 0);                            
ResultSet thisSet =  db.returnBill(number);
while (thisSet.next()){
        String name = thisSet.getString("name");
        int quantity = thisSet.getInt("quantity");
        // do something with the returned data 
        // --------> STUPIDO <----------
        //** Now executing an UPDATE query on db2 :
        // ex.: UPDATE anotherTable SET amount = (current+ "+ quantity+") WHERE name= '" + name+ "' ;";
}
db.closeConn(); // close db ++ 
db2.closeConn(); // closes db 2
```

**I don't know if this is the best approach but it solved my problem, so I'm leaving it so probably it could help. Any suggestions though would be welcomed :D**

Comment: You definitely should use a single connection so that you can have both statements in a single transaction. Did you use two different statement objects?

Comment: If you process a result set and then - while iterating over the result set - execute an update statement on the same Statement object, the result set will be closed. Your use of that database object is a bit counter-intuitive; you might want to consider not hiding the management of connections and statements like you do right now.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I couldn't find these specifics in the documentation related to ResultSet, so thanks a lot. It was hard to explain the detailed view of my DB Connections thoroughly. I was hoping it would be some visible silly mistake due to the lack of experience that's why I didn't post the whole code. Regards :D

Comment: @CL. thanks for the advice. I was actually using only one statement at the same time for both which seems to be the problem.